# For the score_ngrams, how to use just the score of the pair

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I am using pandas dataframe to find ngrams.

The output of `score_ngrams` returns a list of pairs, i.e.

```
[((a, bug), 5.31), ((the, bug), 2.41]
```

I would like to just get the score and multiply it by a variable.  How do I do this?

Comment: Which of the two scores? Please provide an example of what you would want to do.

Comment: So, the score_ngrams returns a list like  A - [[((a, bug), 5.31), ((the, bug), 2.41], B - [((a, bug), 2.31), ((the, bug), 1.41].   I want to comebine the scores into one and remove the ngram so the return is A 7.72, B 3.72

Comment: I am confused. It's a matter of simple indexing, isn't it? `A[0][1]+A[1][1]`.

Comment: You probably want `sum(e[1] for e in A)` or something like that.